# How to convert this Python 2 code to Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This Python code gives a two-dimensional table in version 2. However, in Python 3, it doesn't work:

```py
i = 1
while (i <= 10):
    print (2*i, ' ',)
    i += 1
    print ()
```

The output is:

```
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

Although I have made modifications in `print` statements as required in Python 3, it still does not work.  How can I make this code work in Python 3?

Comment: what's the code and output for your python2 program?

Comment: `print()` calls are not your issue here: http://ideone.com/QOjCG How *else* did you change your code?

Comment: -1 "Doesn't work" is hopeless for us. In what way does it not work. Be precise.

Comment: the output given above is of python 2 program. it should appear in a horizontal line as shown above.                                                                       in python 3 it appears as                                                    2                                                                             4                                                                                6                                                                            8 and so on upto 20

Comment: No extant version of Python produces that output. Please try harder.

Comment: since you have found a solution, please click the grey checkmark next to the answer that helped you most.  this will help everyone else know that this question already has an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Move the second `print` call out of the loop. Inside the loop, a newline is added between every number.

```
i = 1
while (i <= 10):
    print (2*i, ' ',end='')
    i += 1
print()
```

Or, you could replace the while loop (and the `print()` call) with a generator expression:

```
print(*(2*i for i in range(1,11)),sep='  ')
```

Comment: You don't need the `end=''` in the generator version

Answer (score 2):

`print(2*i, ' ',)` isn't the same as Python 2.x `print 2*i, ' ',` because the comma at the end in the function call just acts as a parameter terminator and isn't actually available to the function.

Use `print(2*i, ' ', end = ' ')` in Python 3 to accomplish the same thing (although you can probably leave out the `' '` parameter altogether, and put 2 spaces in the `end` parameter.

Since you've tagged this "pythonic", I should probably also point out that the:

```
i = 1
while i <= 10:
    i += 1
```

pattern isn't very pythonic; the idiom is:

```
for i in range(1,11):
    print(whatever)
```

Answer (score 1):

That code doesn't produce what you say it does on any version of Python. On Python 2, `print(2*i, ' ',)` prints a tuple. On Python 3, `print` is a function and so there is no tuple.

On Python 2 the output is:

```
(2, ' ')
()
(4, ' ')
()
(6, ' ')
()
(8, ' ')
()
(10, ' ')
()
(12, ' ')
()
(14, ' ')
()
(16, ' ')
()
(18, ' ')
()
(20, ' ')
()
```

On Python 3 the output is:

```
2  

4  

6  

8  

10  

12  

14  

16  

18  

20
```

It's impossible to help much more than that until you post the code you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(*(str(2*x) for x in range(1,11)))
```

Or less short:

```
for x in range(1, 11):
    print(2*x, end=' ')
print()
```

Now you figure out what the difference is. :-)

Comment: yeah that worked. that's what i'd been looking for